# LINQ Group results and select from another table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, relational-database

I have the following database structure:

```
table RoadSegment
    int SegmentID
    double StartKm
    double EndKm

table GeographicData
    double Km
    double latitude
    double longitude

table RoadFeature
    int FeatureID
    int SegmentID
```

And I want to select a list of all road features within a certain kilometer range, but i'd also like
to get all of the geographic coordinates in *each* feature's segment. Is there anyway I can do 
this in just one database trip (a single LINQ statement)? I've tried the following:

```
from feat in RoadFeature
from geo in GeographicData
join seg in RoadSegment on feat.SegmentID equals seg.SegmentID

where geo.Km >= seg.StartKm && geo.Km <= seg.EndKm

group feat by feat.FeatureID into grp

select new {
    Feature = grp.Key,
    GeoData = grp.ToList()
}
```

But all I get is, for each feature, a list of features with the same ID. How can i proceed to get,
for each feature, *the list of coordinates on its segment*? That is, I'd like to have the following
result out of the query:

```
[
    {
        FeatureID: 1,
        GeoData: [
            [-11.786783, 22.4567864],
            [-11.654684, 22.6546548],
            [-11.646648, 22.7867544]
        ]
    },

    {
        FeatureID: 2,
        GeoData: [
            [-11.111265, 22.4118787],
            [-11.568746, 22.6546548],
            [-11.124687, 22.0121571]
        ]
    }
]
```

Some data:

```
RoadSegment
    ID      StartKm     EndKm
    41      57.6        69.4
    42      69.4        80
    43      80          86.5
    44      86.5        92.2
    45      92.2        126
    46      126         132

RoadFeature
    FeatureID   SegmentID
    1           41
    2           42
    3           43
    4           44
    5           45
    6           46

GeographicData
    Km          latitude        longitude
    57.62       -19.959059      -44.339733          
    57.622      -19.959121      -44.339793          
    57.631      -19.959182      -44.339857          
    57.641      -19.959249      -44.339922          
    57.651      -19.959317      -44.339989          
    57.661      -19.959387      -44.340062          
    57.672      -19.959465      -44.340145          
    57.684      -19.959548      -44.340232          
    57.697      -19.959632      -44.340322          
    57.71       -19.959721      -44.340419          
    57.724      -19.959815      -44.340522          
    57.739      -19.959913      -44.34063           
    57.755      -19.960013      -44.340739          
    57.771      -19.960114      -44.340846          
    57.787      -19.960213      -44.34095
```

(Point is, there is 1 feature per segment, but a WHOLE LOT of geo-data per
kilometer. Also, i'd like solutions which don't rely on the uniqueness of
feature per segment, if possible)

Comment: could you post some of your data ?

Comment: @Noctis yes, just edited :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you just need to add `geo` in your grouping.

Then you can select these datas in your anonymous type.

So

```
from feat in RoadFeature
from geo in GeographicData
join seg in RoadSegment on feat.SegmentID equals seg.SegmentID

where geo.Km >= seg.StartKm && geo.Km <= seg.EndKm

group new {feat, geo} by feat.FeatureID into grp

select new {
    Feature = grp.Key,
    GeoData = grp.Select(x => x.geo).ToList()
}
```